# how to pass value to input time tag using ng-model

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, datetime

Hi i am trying to pass value to a input time tag, from javascript - angular JS. 
Here is the following code.

**JS** :

```
$scope.from="09:00:00"
$scope.from="17:00:00"
```

**HTML** :

```
From : <input type="time" ng-model="from" > 
To : <input type="time" ng-model="to" >
```

No value is getting updated inside input element. what is the mistake in above code?

Here is the Full code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

From: <input type="time" ng-model="fromTime"><br>
To: <input type="time" ng-model="toTime"><br>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.fromTime="09:00:00";
    $scope.toTime="17:00:00";
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

---

> Error: [ngModel:datefmt]

Comment: The JS code have same scope variable `$scope.from`

Comment: it is not working with other name even.

Comment: do you get a console error?

Comment: This code should work, we need to see how you created the module and controller and how you defined them in the view

Comment: yes. Error: [ngModel:datefmt]

Answer (score 1):

After angularjs version 1.3, all date related inputs require a model of type Date().
[documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btime%5D)

So you need to change the values to Date objects like this e.g. :

```
$scope.from= new Date(1970, 0, 1, 09, 0, 0);
$scope.to= new Date(1970, 0, 1, 17, 0, 0);
```

Check the demo: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rqufzLpj/7/)

Answer (score 0):

From the Docs:

> ## Error: ngModel:datefmt
>
> ## Model is not a date object
>
> ### Description
>
> All date-related inputs like `<input type="date">` require the model to be a `Date` object. If the model is something else, this error will be thrown.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Error Reference - Error: ngModel:datefmt](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngModel/datefmt)